# Getting the context from a DialogFragment opened by a adapter

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am having losts of issues with a DialogFragment that is opened from a Recylerview adapter that is linked to a recyclerview that is in a fragment from an activity.

I don´t really know if this structure is very common.

I want to put a video player library inside the Dialogfragment, but there is an issue on the line:

```
player=new MKPlayer((Activity) mContext);
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.app.Activity.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at com.khizar1556.mkvideoplayer.MKPlayer.<init>
```

I am defining the context as follows:

```
Context mContext = getActivity() ;
```

I guess the context definition is the source for the exception.

Comment: Instead of trying to get the activity context directly from the fragment, try passing in the activity as a parameter to the fragment, and when attaching, just assign it to a member variable?

Comment: Move your initialization code to `onCreate`, context will be null until fragment attaches.

Comment: Fragments don't support parameters in constructor.

Comment: I advice you to share more information with us about your code. Show us how you implemented your DialogFragment.